# Can we delete an attribute of a document in firestore automatically?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an android project using java where we have a subscription for pro users. Right now I am using firestore as my database, is there any way that I can automatically change the pro attribute in user from true to false in a specific time automatically as the subscription time end? In my user collection's document, there are attributes is_a_pro and pro_availability_time which is in json (YYYY-MM-DD). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into Firestore to automatically change documents at a given time.

The most common solution is to [schedule a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), that runs periodically, and then check which subscriptions have expired.

An alternative to running them periodically is to schedule a Cloud Task for when each subscription expires. For an example of how to do that, see Doug's blog post [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).